# VPN routing issue in linux- how to make applications that can only bind to IP addresses work?

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, curl, rtorrent

Right now I have a PPTP VPN set up on my remote ubuntu VPS. I would like to have certain applications use the VPN to access the internet (rtorrent, irssi, among others). Currently, it is set up like this:

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:94:38:ce
>             inet addr:66.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:66.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
> eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:d7:58:a1
>             inet addr:10.2.0.111  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>
> ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
>             inet addr:192.168.10.244  P-t-P:192.168.9.1  Mask:255.255.255.255

Essentially, the way I've seen this issue manifest is like this.

When I run

```
curl --interface eth0 checkip.dyndns.com
```

I get

```
<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 66.xxx.xxx.xxx</body></html>
```

And when I run

```
curl --interface ppp0 checkip.dyndns.com
```

I get

```
<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 95.xxx.xxx.xxx</body></html>
```

Which is correct.

However, when I run

```
curl --interface 192.168.10.244 checkip.dyndns.com
```

it times out and I get nothing. Which doesn't seem to make any sense, as 192.168.10.244 is the IP address of ppp0, and it doesn't seem to me that it should be any different from the above command. Am I missing something? If I can get this to work in curl, I'll be able to get it to work in rtorrent and irssi as I would like as well, curl is just easier to test for this sort of thing. Are there any good starting points for tackling this problem?

EDIT:
Fixed it! Here is how I did it.

First I created a new routing table:

```
# echo "200 vpn" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Then, I created a rule for requests sourced from my ppp0 IP address to lookup from that new table

```
# ip rule add from 192.168.10.244 table 200
```

Then, I created a rule in that table to use ppp0.

```
# ip route add default dev ppp0 table 200
```

It works perfectly! Now when I attempt the previously failing curl command:

```
# curl --interface 192.168.10.244 checkip.dyndns.com
<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 95.xxx.xxx.xxx</body></html>
```

Comment: which commands did you use for that configuration ? i'm looking for a solution but couldn't find anything works.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is incorrect. Binding to an IP address only chooses the source IP address. It has no effect on the route taken to the destination, which is what you want to control.

To do what you want to do, you need to set up a form of policy routing called source based routing. This is typically done by creating two routing tables, one for each connection, and deciding the routing table to use based on the local source IP address. See any of the many [howto](http://muchtall.com/2007/08/06/24/)s on [policy routing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7291).

Comment: I tried this, and am having the following issue
 
    #echo 200 vpns >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

    #ip rule add from 192.168.10.244 table vpns

    #ip route add default via 192.168.9.1 dev ppp0 table vpns
    RTNETLINK answers: No such process

Comment: ugh, tried to make it look correct, but basically when I perform the command "ip route add default via 192.168.9.1 dev ppp0 table vpns" I get "RNETLINK answers: No such process". Is that the incorrect command?

Comment: You mean "table 200", right? Routing tables are numbered.

Comment: Still the same result. RNETLINK answers: No such process.

Comment: Maybe your VPS doesn't support policy routing.

Comment: Disregard- I made it work! editing my OP to show how I did it.

Comment: Looks good. Just make sure traffic with that source IP address doesn't ever need to go anyplace else. If it does, add another route to that table. Also, you may want to make sure the default source IP is the one you want it to be by placing `src` parameters on your routes.